# Set select value based on h1 text

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have the following form:

```js
$(function() {
    if () {}
    else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sandeep</h1>
<form>
    <select>
        <option>Non Selected</option>
        <option selected>Michael</option>
        <option>Sandeep</option>
    </select>   
</form>
```

I want to find a way to say in javascript: if the text of the `h1` is `Sandeep` the option selected will be `sandeep`.

I don't know how to define the condition inside the `if` statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to directly set the value of `select` tag to that of the text inside `h1`.

**JS CODE:**

```
$(function () {
   var selectedText = $('h1').text();
   $('select').val(selectedText);
});
```

**Live demo @ JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/k151ye9h/**

Comment: Glad that was helpful, happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.text()` to get the text in the `<h1>`, and compare that with `Sandeep`. Use `.val()` to set the value of the `<select>`

```js
if ($("h1").text() == "Sandeep") {
  $("select").val("Sandeep");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sandeep</h1>
<form>
  <select>
    <option>Non Selected</option>
    <option selected>Michael</option>
    <option>Sandeep</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See inline comments

```js
$(function() {
    var text=$('.name').text(); //get the header value by referring its class
    $('select').find("option[text=" + text + "]").attr("selected", true);
    //^^Find that particular option whose text is same as in header
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="name">Sandeep</h1>
<form>
    <select>
      <option>Non Selected</option>
      <option text="Micheal" selected>Michael</option> 
      <option text="Sandeep">Sandeep</option>
      <!--Add text property to each option-->
    </select>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Jquery selector to select the value based on "h1".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("h1").text() == "Sandeep") {
    $("select").val("Sandeep");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Sandeep</h1>
<form>
  <select>
    <option>Non Selected</option>
    <option selected>Michael</option>
    <option>Sandeep</option>
  </select>
</form>
```